# Angular: How to pass through an output as part of an input?

Tags: angular

I have a component for a modal window that is customisable. The modal can have any number of buttons, that will do any number of different tasks and functions.

Because the buttons have customisable text and styling as well as the callback, I want to pass through an interface that looks similar to this:

```js
enum ButtonType {
    basic = 'basic',
    primary = 'primary',
    tertiary = 'tertiary',
}

export interface IModalButton {
    text: string;
    type?: ButtonType;
    callback: any; // Not sure what to set this to, it didn't like being set to EventEmitter
}
```

To then pass through a simple close button as an example, I have these properties in a parent class:

```js
    modalContent = '';
    modalTitle = '';
    isVisible = false;
    buttons: IModalButton[] = [
        {
            callback: this.toggleVisibility,
            text: 'Close',
        },
    ];

    toggleVisibility() {
        this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;
    }
```

And then I'm passing those properties through to the child like so:

```html
<exp-modal *ngIf="isVisible" [title]="modalTitle" (close)="toggleVisibility();" [buttons]="buttons">
    <p>{{ modalContent }}</p>
</exp-modal>
```

The problem I have is, that when I call the function in the child component, it runs it as though it is in the child component (it changes isVisible in the child component). I also can't work out how this can be done with event emitters either because my `buttons` array needs to sort of be passed in as both `@Input()` and `@Output()`. There is an actual separate close button at the top right that will always be there and currently does work, so I know `toggleVisibility();` itself is working fine.

So my question is, how can I pass through an array of objects to a child component where the callback to a parent component is nested within the objects?

Various different things that I've tried can be found here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/modal-buttons-test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get around it by passing through a separate output to the child.

Parent HTML:

```html
<exp-modal *ngIf="isVisible" [title]="modalTitle" [buttons]="buttons" (close)="toggleVisibility()"
           (buttonEvent)="modalService.executeCallback($event)">
  <p>{{ modalContent }}</p>
</exp-modal>
```

Parent Typescript:

```js
isVisible = false;
buttons: IModalButton[] = [
    {
        callback: this.toggleVisibility.bind(this),
        text: 'Close',
    },
];

constructor(
    readonly modalService: ModalService,
) { }

toggleVisibility() {
    this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;
}
```

Service:

```js
export class ModalService {
    executeCallback(callback: Function) {
        callback();
    }
}
```

Child HTML:

```html
<button *ngFor="let button of buttons; index as i" class="eds-button eds-button.{{button.type}}"
        (click)="sendCallback(button.callback);">
    <span class="eds-button_#label">{{button.text}}</span>
</button>
```

Child Typescript:

```js
@Input() buttons: IModalButton[];
@Output() buttonEvent = new EventEmitter();

sendCallback(callback: Function) {
    this.buttonEvent.emit(callback);
}
```

The full solution has been updated on the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/modal-buttons-test

Answer (score 0):

for me to pass output to another element input, I'm using this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child1',
  template: `<button (click)=fireEvent()>Test</button>`,
})
export class Child1Component {

  @Output() valueChanged = new EventEmitter<string>();

  fireEvent() {
    this.valueChanged.emit("new value");
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'child2',
  template: `<h1>{{value}}</h1>`,
})
export class Child2Component {

  @Input() value?: string;

}

@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `
    <child1 (valueChanged)="updated = $event"></child1>
    <child2 [value]="updated"></child2>
  `,
})
export class ParentComponent {

  updated?: string;

}
```